# Lua and native code in Kony Studio

Tags: objective-c, lua, code-generation, temenos-quantum

I am trying to understand the "write once deploy anywhere" feature of Kony Studio.  What about native code?  I know that Kony added JavaScript support in V5 but as I understand it that is just for the Web-based app portion.  Am I correct to assume that native code is still written with Lua and then generated for each platform?  Do they convert Lua to Java, Objective-C and C# for the 3 main platforms?  When debugging are you looking at Lua or the native language?  - Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added to we can choose the developing language from javascript or Lua. If we choose Lua then instead of V8 engine it will be Lua Virtual machine that which is doing the interpretation.

Answer (score 5):

Kony embeds the google v8 js engine along with the native app. This will interprets the js code to native at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is still used for scripting against the Kony API. LUA is not necessary for native apps. Remember that the API is an abstraction layer to the underlying native SDK - Kony is not a code gen tool.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery.  That helps knowing it all can be JavaScript, no Lua necessary.  So is the JavaScript interpreted at runtime or is there any cross-compilation for each platform?  If cross-compilation, is C# the native language for Windows Phone or Windows 8, so JavaScript (rather than Lua any more) is converted to C#?

Comment: I have learned that Kony uses an embedded JavaScript engine per each platform, usually using the platform's own, to interpret the JS that you write in.

Comment: KonyOne platform interprets JavaScript at runtime always on each platform.  Appcelerator Titanium mobile platform generates some part of the application to platform specific native language code at compile time and uses that at runtime.